# Can Jenny Barnes' enable someone to use acquire assets a second time?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-signs-of-carcosa

Can Jenny Barnes' use her ability to allow herself or another investigator to use acquire assets if the target investigator has already performed it? Typically you cannot perform the same action twice in one round, but would this special ability that induces an acquire assets action count as performing acquire assets twice? If so, one would think the same holds for disallowing a player to move spaces after they have moved before, counting it as a "travel".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is similar to Charlie Kane's special action. The investigator must not already have performed the same action during the current round.

From the official [errata](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/e3/a5/e3a58886-072b-4ca2-9709-e723af370203/eh_errata__faq_2016-01-19.pdf):

> **Can an investigator’s “additional” action be used to perform an
>   action he has already performed in that round?**
>
> No. An investigator may perform an action only once
>   each round, even if he is able to perform an additional action,
>   such as from the Ruby of R’lyeh Artifact or Charlie Kane’s
>   action ability.

There is no reason to suppose that Jenny's ability overrules this limitation.

For reference, here is the actual text of Jenny's special:

> **Action:** You or another investigator on a City space may perform an Acquire Assets action and gain +2 Influence during that action.

However, if Jenny uses her special action to allow *another* investigator to perform an acquire asset action (and gaining the +2 bonus to influence), she can, herself, still perform the acquire asset action normally (no +2 influence bonus).